# How to add multiple ternary operators in html code?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, svg

Let us consider I am having following code :
It used to apply css class upto **red4** , but I need to apply css classes upto **red11** and myData is having **size** , I would like to have that size is dynamic manner.
For eg: Size would be having dynamic number range , 0 - 20 // 0 - 100 // 0 - 10000 etc. color range should depends upon the dynamic size range.

HTML :

```
<svg><path *ngFor="let item of myData" [attr.class]="item.myColor=='red1'?'red1':item.myColor=='red2'?'red2':item.myColor=='red3'?'red3':item.myColor=='red4'?'red4':null"></path>
</svg>
```

Here is my css classes :

```
svg path.red1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ffcccc;
}
svg path.red2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ffb3b3;
}
svg path.red3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff9999;
}
svg path.red4 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff6666;
}
svg path.red5 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff4d4d;
}
svg path.red6 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff3333;
}
svg path.red7 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff1a1a;
}
svg path.red8 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #ff0000;
}
svg path.red9 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #e60000;
}
svg path.red10 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #cc0000;
}
svg path.red11 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #b30000;
}
```

Here is a typescript code :

```
export interface DataInterface {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  size: number;
  myColor: string;
  myCheck: string;
  d: string;
  class?: string;
}
myList = [{ "id": "SG-05", "size": 30, }, { "id": "SG-04", "size": 9, }, { "id": "SG-01", "size": 20, }];

myData: DataInterface[] = [
  {
    "id": "SG-01", "size": 20, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false'
  },
  {
    "id": "SG-02",  "size": 20, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', 
  },
  {
    "id": "SG-03", "size": 20, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', 
  },
  {
    "id": "SG-04",  "size": 40, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', 
  },
  {
    "id": "SG-05",  "size": 70, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false',
  },
]

fillColor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
    let myCountry = this.myData[i].id;
    for (let j = 0; j < this.myList.length; j++) {
      if (myCountry === this.myList[j].id) {
        this.myData[i].size = this.myList[j].size;
        if (myCountry === this.myList[j].id && this.myList[j].size <= 0) {
          this.myData[i].myColor = 'red1';
        }
        else if (myCountry === this.myList[j].id && this.myList[j].size <= 10) {
          this.myData[i].myColor = 'red2';
        }
        else if (myCountry === this.myList[j].id && this.myList[j].size <= 20) {
          this.myData[i].myColor = 'red3';
        }
        else if (myCountry === this.myList[j].id && this.myList[j].size <= 30) {
          this.myData[i].myColor = 'red4';
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('$$$$$$$$$$2', this.myData);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also

```
[ngClass]="item.myColor"
```

BTW, you can reemplace your function fillColor by

```
this.myData.forEach((x:any)=>{
  const country=this.myList.find(l=>l.id==x.id)
  if (country)
  {
       x.size=country.size;
       x.myColor='red'+(Math.floor(country.size/10)+1)
  }
})
```

using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) array's methods

Answer (score 1):

Since `item.myColor` returns color name you can just set 
`[attr.class] = "item.myColor ? item.myColor : null"`